# Do women also wear white on Yom Kippur?

Tags: minhag, women, clothing, yom-kippur, color

Is it customary for women to wear white clothing on Yom Kippur, or is it largely a custom men observe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Mishna Brurah 610:16 says women customarily wear white and clean clothes. Not sure what people do today.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen a lot of women do it -- maybe not quite the same percentage as men, but it's not unheard-of.

I don't know of particular standard-identity communal practices, though. (E.g. I don't know what dyed-in-the-wool Chabad women do, nor Satmar or the like.)

The general thing to keep in mind is to be dressed appropriately. (I think some women, in some circumstances, might find white tricky to pull off in an appropriate way, but that's not for me to dictate.)

Comment: "dyed-in-the-wool" -- heh

Comment: Ok - the women at my Chabad shul and the other orthodox shuls wore white as well. Yom Kippur publication at Chabad shul encouraged everyone to wear white and men to wear a kittel...

Comment: I daven at Chabad shuls and no one wears white.